# Changing UIDeviceOrientationDidChange limits

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am wondering if there are ways in changing the limits for which UIDeviceOrientationDidChange results in orientation of isFaceUp. My current problem is that I detect when the device orientation isFaceUp and show a map, but with the strict default limits at which it gets called, the user really has to struggle to not rotate the phone to much or the map will disappear.

If this is not possible is there another way of tracking sensors in the phone manually to achieve the same result with custom values defined?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> If this is not possible is there another way of tracking sensors in the phone manually

Yes, you should be tracking the phone's actual orientation using the Core Motion framework.

Comment: Here's example code doing basically just the thing you're describing, i.e. detecting whether, within certain limits, we are lying face up: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch22p782lyingDown/ch25p1039lyingDown/ViewController.swift

Comment: Awesome, thank you for sharing that example! I will try it out in our project ASAP.